# How to get a pointer to function as u32?

Tags: function, pointers, rust

How can I get a pointer to function as `u32` value?

I have a function that taking a pointer to function:

```
fn getter_of_functions<T>(pointer: T) {
    // ...
    /* 

    This code don't compile ...
    let fun_ptr: u32 = unsafe {
        mem::transmute::<T, u32>(callback)
    };

    */
}

fn function() {
    println!("hello ...");
}

getter_of_functions(function);
```

How to get it (I have to have a generic function)? Often error I had is:

```
cannot transmute to or from a type that contains unsubstituted type parameters
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't.

`T` could be anything; it could be a function pointer, a `u32`, an `i32`, an `f64`, a `String`, a `Box<[Arc<Mutex<Vec<&[Box<Goombah>]>>>]>`, or even `()`: nothing at all.  The compiler has no way of knowing if the transmute is even remotely *possible*, let alone *correct*.

This is because you *do not* have a function taking a "pointer to function".  You have a function taking an "absolutely anything".  If you're treating Rust generics like C++/D templates, you need to understand that they do not work the same way.  Rust checks its templates at *definition* time based on what you've told it about the types involved.  For example, the only thing you can do with a completely generic `T` is move it.  That you've instantiated the generic function such that `T` is a function type is irrelevant: by the time that happens, Rust will have already decided whether or not the generic code is valid or not.

> To use a different analogy: Rust generics are to C++ templates what C++ typing is to Python typing: static and done ahead-of-time instead of ad-hoc and done on-demand.

So, how do you specify that you want some kind of pointer-to-function?  You can't.

There is no way to specify any arbitrary kind of function pointer.  Rust doesn't have variadic generics, so you can't express the idea of a variable number of types, which you'd need for the argument list.

There are the `Fn*` traits, but using those is only going to make the situation worse.  Since you haven't explained *why* you're trying to do this, it's hard to know what you should be doing instead.

What you *can* do is ask for a specific *shape* of function pointer.

```
fn getter_0_args<R>(f: fn() -> R) { ... }
fn getter_2_args<A0, A1, R>(f: fn(A0, A1) -> R) { ... }
```

Or you could just do the cast in the *calling* code:

```
getter_1_arg(f as fn(_) -> _ as usize)
```

(I'm using `_` here to let inference fill in the argument and return types for me.)

Which brings me to my last point: using transmute for this is *entirely* unnecessary when `as` works *just fine*.  Also, using `u32` for this is *wrong*: you should be using `usize` or `isize` for pointer- and length-sized things.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to cast the function pointer to `usize` rather than `u32`.

```
fn foo(ptr: fn()) {
    let n = ptr as usize;
    println!("{}", n);
}

fn a() {}

fn b() {}

fn main() {
    foo(a);
    foo(b);
}
```

Comment: Yes, this code work, but how I said I want a generic function. I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

`fn`-pointers don't seem to implement any useful common trait you can rely on as a bound. It would be nice if they at least implemented `Into<usize>` or `Into<*mut T>`, but since they don't, the trick is to create your own trait and use some macro magic to implement it for all `fn`-pointers up to a certain arity. This is how I did it for [minhook-rs](https://github.com/Jascha-N/minhook-rs/blob/master/src/function.rs).

Here is a simplified implementation:

```
use std::mem;

pub trait Function: Sized {
    unsafe fn from_usize(value: usize) -> Self;
    fn to_usize(&self) -> usize;
}

macro_rules! impl_function {
    (recurse: () ($($ty:ident),*)) => {
        impl_function!(impl_cc: ($($ty),*));
    };
    (recurse: ($hd:ident $(, $tl:ident)*) ($($ty:ident),*)) => {
        impl_function!(impl_cc: ($($ty),*));
        impl_function!(recurse: ($($tl),*) ($($ty,)* $hd));
    };

    (impl_cc: ($($ty:ident),*)) => {
        impl_function!(impl_fun: ($($ty),*) (                  fn($($ty),*) -> Ret));
        // impl_function!(impl_fun: ($($ty),*) (extern "cdecl"    fn($($ty),*) -> Ret));
        // impl_function!(impl_fun: ($($ty),*) (extern "stdcall"  fn($($ty),*) -> Ret));
        // impl_function!(impl_fun: ($($ty),*) (extern "fastcall" fn($($ty),*) -> Ret));
        // impl_function!(impl_fun: ($($ty),*) (extern "win64"    fn($($ty),*) -> Ret));
        // impl_function!(impl_fun: ($($ty),*) (extern "C"        fn($($ty),*) -> Ret));
        // impl_function!(impl_fun: ($($ty),*) (extern "system"   fn($($ty),*) -> Ret));

        // Uncomment/add more if needed
    };

    (impl_fun: ($($ty:ident),*) ($fn_type:ty)) => {
        impl<Ret, $($ty),*> Function for $fn_type {
            unsafe fn from_usize(value: usize) -> Self {
                mem::transmute(value)
            }

            fn to_usize(&self) -> usize {
                *self as usize
            }
        }
    };

    ($($ty:ident),*) => {
        impl_function!(recurse: ($($ty),*) ());
    };
}

// Implement Function for up to 12 arguments
impl_function!(A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L);

fn getter_of_functions<F: Function>(function: F) {
    let fun_ptr = function.to_usize();
    println!("{:x}", fun_ptr);
}

fn function() {
    println!("hello ...");
}

fn main() {
    getter_of_functions(function as fn());
}
```

As has been stated before, you should use `usize` as opposed to `u32`.